# ¿Cómo ajustar el Pitch (tono) en Visual Basic?

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando cambiar el tono de las voces en Visual Basic, pero no encuentro manera de hacerlo.

Se puede cambiar el Rate y el Volume, pero el tono no hay manera.

¿Hay alguna forma de poder cambiarlo?

Este es el código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading;

namespace Text_to_Speech
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //speech synthesizer
    private SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        #region synthesizer eventes
        synthesizer.StateChanged += new EventHandler<StateChangedEventArgs>(synthesizer_StateChanged);
        synthesizer.SpeakStarted += new EventHandler<SpeakStartedEventArgs>(synthesizer_SpeakStarted);
        synthesizer.SpeakProgress += new EventHandler<SpeakProgressEventArgs>(synthesizer_SpeakProgress);
        synthesizer.SpeakCompleted += new EventHandler<SpeakCompletedEventArgs>(synthesizer_SpeakCompleted); 
        #endregion

        LoadInstalledVoices();
    }

    //bind installed voices to the combo based on current culture
    private void LoadInstalledVoices()
    {
        comboVoice.DataContext = (from e in synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
                                  select e.VoiceInfo.Name);
    }

    private void ButtonSpeak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboVoice.SelectedItem != null)
        synthesizer.SelectVoice(comboVoice.SelectedItem.ToString());
        synthesizer.Volume = Convert.ToInt32(sliderVolume.Value);
        synthesizer.Rate = Convert.ToInt32(sliderRate.Value);
        switch (synthesizer.State)
        {
                //if synthesizer is ready
            case SynthesizerState.Ready:
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync(ConvertRichTextBoxContentsToString());
                ButtonSpeak.Content = "Pause";
                break;
                //if synthesizer is paused
            case SynthesizerState.Paused:
                synthesizer.Resume();
                ButtonSpeak.Content = "Pause";
                break;
                //if synthesizer is speaking
            case SynthesizerState.Speaking:
                synthesizer.Pause();
                ButtonSpeak.Content = "Resume";
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OpenTextFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            LoadTextDocument(openFileDialog.FileName);
            FileNameTextBox.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
        }
    }


    private void LoadTextDocument(string fileName)
    {
        TextRange range;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            range = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
            using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                range.Load(fStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Text);
            }
        }
    }

    string ConvertRichTextBoxContentsToString()
    {
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
        return textRange.Text;
    }

    #region Synthesizer events
    private void synthesizer_StateChanged(object sender, StateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //show the synthesizer's current state 
        labelState.Content = e.State.ToString();
    }
    private void synthesizer_SpeakStarted(object sender, SpeakStartedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void synthesizer_SpeakProgress(object sender, SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        //show the synthesizer's current progress 
        labelProgress.Content = e.Text;
    }

    private void synthesizer_SpeakCompleted(object sender, SpeakCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //reset when complete 
        ButtonSpeak.Content = "Speak";
        labelProgress.Content = "";
    } 
    #endregion

    private void sliderVolume_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (synthesizer != null)
        {
            synthesizer.Volume = Convert.ToInt32(sliderVolume.Value);
        }
    }

    private void sliderRate_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        if (synthesizer != null)
            synthesizer.Rate = Convert.ToInt32(sliderRate.Value);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: No se para que quiere usar usted el Pitch, pero  mirando la documentacion -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer_members(v=office.14).aspx no puedo ver nada sobre pitch directamente como puedo ver sobre Rate ect, pero si la intencion de usted es alterar un poco la voz puede que esto le ayude -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd167486(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: En el primer link puede ver algunos metodos con este nombre mas o menos SelectVoiceBy.... que le pueden ayudar, algunos toma como parametros aparte del Enum un int32 igual le ayude de alguna manera, SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender, VoiceAge, Int32) Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Angel. Probaré y avisaré sobre los resultados. Gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, con el SpeechSynthesizer no se puede ajustar el pitch(tono). Efectivamente se puede cambiar el Rate(velocidad) y Volume(volúmen), también el Emphasys(énfasis) que admite los valores:

**Moderate**    Indica un nivel de énfasis moderado.

**None**    Indica que no hay ningún énfasis.

**NotSet**  Indica que no se especifica ningún valor de énfasis.

**Reduced** Indica un nivel reducido de énfasis.

**Strong**  Indica un nivel de énfasis fuerte.

Pero no permite ir más allá.